# how this span is not visible in the select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I have the code for select box and am using Jquery mobile .The problem is that in the select box the span tag the value is not visible even is the value is selected .But Problem its taking all the properties except this properties and then how to do that?

```css
//Here is code for visible the Span
#term-button  span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML generated after select box.-->
<label id="Semesterlbl" class="select">Semester you expect to enter University:</label>
<div class="ui-select">
  <div class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow" id="term-button">
    <span style="display: none;">2014-2015 SUM A</span>
    <!-- Term Plans -->
    <select id="term" name="term">
      <option value="1406" selected="">2014-2015 SUM A</option>
      <option value="1501">2015-2016 FALL</option>;
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline` style has the highest `priority`

Comment: I m not sure I understood the question, but if the issue is that you do not see the span it might have to do with the span style="display: none;"

Comment: instead of the generated html, show us your source HTML so we can see why the span gets hidden. Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I added an answer. You need to refresh the widget after adding dynamic options.

Answer (score 2):

`<span style="display: none;">2014-2015 SUM A</span>`

You can see it has an inline css of `display:none;` and it has the priority over the other one. so remove it and it would be visible.

if you are asking for a js solution then you can use this:

```
$('#term-button > span:hidden').show();
```

Comment: Then override it with js. @SnehasishDas

Answer (score 0):

After adding dynamic options to the selectmenu widget, make sure to **[refresh()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** the widget:

```
$("#term").selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yw1ny2un/)